Compile + build java bazel project using flatbuffers
I have a java project that's built using bazel, and I'd like to make use of flatbuffers. I'm having a hard time finding good examples of how to make use of the open source build targets which should handle generating the java classes and then compiling the code with them. I see this ticket in their public repo claiming they do in fact have publicly available build targets, as well as this module in the bazel central registry, but my project is still using the legacy WORKSPACE setup so the snippet given in the registry doesn't work (or at least, I'm too n00bish with bazel to know how to make it work).
So, I have two questions:

How do I go from the snippet in the registry to something compatible with the older WORKSPACE setup? I assume it'll look something like this using http_archive, right?
Once imported, how do I look up what build functions are now available to me in my project? And is one of them what I'm hoping for, ie something equivalent to proto_library and java_proto_library, except for flatbuffers?

Also, if you have an equivalent answer in some other language (say python or c++), I guess it should look quite similar in java so I should hopefully be able to adapt it, so feel free to share examples in any language.
